# Drawing a progress animation in custom view(Button) using canvas in Android

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-custom-view

I want to draw a progress animation in a button from left to right somewhat like this:

[image]

Here the button nothing but a custom view. So the canvas should draw this and I have to extend view class only. I am not sure what should I use here I tried using canvas.drawPath using a value animator but no success. 
I am not sure which canvas method should be used here and how I can animate it from left to right.
Can anyone help me here, please?

Answer (score 1):

To start with the custom view, keep in mind of the following points

1. As it dictates it's a progress indicator view with text over it. So
   choose TextView to extend the functionality.
2. The background animates here, that means our progress draw part has
   to be done before original textview draw cycle.
3. It's wise to keep the progress update outside the custom view.

With this in mind the custom view will look as below

```
class DownloadButton : androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView {

    /// constructor


    private val bgPaint: Paint = Paint().apply {
        color = 0xff216353.toInt()
    }

    private val progressPaint: Paint = Paint().apply {
        color = 0xff75daad.toInt()
    }

    var progress: Float = 0f

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {

        // Draw before original content drawn
        // Compute the dx based on the progress
        // and draw 2 rects

        canvas?.let {
            val dx = it.width * progress
            it.drawRect(RectF(0f, 0f, dx, it.height * 1f), bgPaint)
            it.drawRect(RectF(dx, 0f, it.width * 1f, it.height * 1f), progressPaint)
        }

        super.onDraw(canvas)
    }

    fun updateProgress(progress: Float) {
        this.progress = progress
        val percent = (progress * 100).toInt()
        text = "Progress $percent%"
        invalidate()
    }

}
```

Use it in xml as any TextView used

```
<com.example.custom.DownloadButton
        android:id="@+id/downloadButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="Download"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:typeface="monospace" />
```

Anywhere in the code, call downloadButton.updateProgress() to redraw the progress.

> Note this is a bare minimum implementation where we haven't done computation optimization for edge cases (0 - 100) progress where drawing one rect would be suffice

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me , hope it also help you out !

LoadingButton.kt

```
import android.animation.AnimatorInflater
import android.animation.ValueAnimator
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.*
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.View
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import kotlin.properties.Delegates


class LoadingButton @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

private var bgColor: Int = Color.BLACK
private var textColor: Int = Color.BLACK // default color

private var widthSize = 0
private var heightSize = 0

@Volatile
private var progress: Double = 0.0

private var valueAnimator: ValueAnimator

private var buttonState: ButtonState by Delegates.observable(ButtonState.Completed) { 
  p, old, new ->
}

private val updateListener = ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener {
    progress = (it.animatedValue as Float).toDouble()

    invalidate()
    requestLayout()
}

fun hasCompletedDownload() {
    // cancel the animation when file is downloaded
    valueAnimator.cancel()

    buttonState = ButtonState.Completed
    invalidate()
    requestLayout()
}


init {
    isClickable = true

    valueAnimator = AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(
        context, R.animator.loading_animation
    ) as ValueAnimator

    valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(updateListener)

    val attr = context.theme.obtainStyledAttributes(
        attrs,
        R.styleable.LoadingButton,
        0,
        0
    )
    try {
        bgColor = attr.getColor(
            R.styleable.LoadingButton_bgColor,
            ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary)
        )

        textColor = attr.getColor(
            R.styleable.LoadingButton_textColor,
            ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary)
        )
    } finally {
        attr.recycle()
    }
  }

private val paint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG).apply {
    style = Paint.Style.FILL
    textAlign = Paint.Align.CENTER
    textSize = 55.0f
    typeface = Typeface.create("", Typeface.BOLD)
}

override fun performClick(): Boolean {
    super.performClick()
    if (buttonState == ButtonState.Completed) buttonState = ButtonState.Loading
    animation()

    return true
}

private fun animation() {
    valueAnimator.start()
}

private val rect = RectF(
    740f,
    50f,
    810f,
    110f
)


override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas)
    paint.strokeWidth = 0f
    paint.color = bgColor
    canvas.drawRect(0f, 0f, width.toFloat(), height.toFloat(), paint)


    if (buttonState == ButtonState.Loading) {
        paint.color = Color.parseColor("#004349")
        canvas.drawRect(
            0f, 0f,
            (width * (progress / 100)).toFloat(), height.toFloat(), paint
        )
        paint.color = Color.parseColor("#F9A825")
        canvas.drawArc(rect, 0f, (360 * (progress / 100)).toFloat(), true, paint)
    }
    val buttonText =
        if (buttonState == ButtonState.Loading)
            resources.getString(R.string.loading)
        else resources.getString(R.string.download)

    paint.color = textColor
    canvas.drawText(buttonText, (width / 2).toFloat(), ((height + 30) / 2).toFloat(), 
 paint)
}

override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
    val minw: Int = paddingLeft + paddingRight + suggestedMinimumWidth
    val w: Int = resolveSizeAndState(minw, widthMeasureSpec, 1)
    val h: Int = resolveSizeAndState(
        MeasureSpec.getSize(w),
        heightMeasureSpec,
        0
    )
    widthSize = w
    heightSize = h
    setMeasuredDimension(w, h)
   }
}
```

call hasCompletedDownload() function when file got downloaded in order to stop the animation.

Add a new file (say attrs.xml) in "values" folder under "res" folder to add attributes for custom button.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <declare-styleable name="LoadingButton">
    <attr name="bgColor" format="integer" />
    <attr name="textColor" format="integer" />
   </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Add this in your layout

```
 <com.android.example.LoadingButton
    android:id="@+id/custom_button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    app:textColor="@color/white"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Add another folder  (say animation) under "res" folder then add a file "loading_animation.xml" in order to add animation attributes for the custom button.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="500"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
android:valueFrom="0f"
android:valueTo="100f"
android:valueType="floatType" />
```

Thank You :)